# Refresh Google API access token with Expo SDK?

Tags: javascript, react-native, fetch, google-oauth, expo

I've followed the guide [Google login / Expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/google) and got both access token and refresh token.

But after access token expiring I can't get the new token.

When I try to get new one I get this error:

`"error": "unauthorized_client", "error_description": "Unauthorized"`

Here is the sample of the sent request for getting the new access token ([Google docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer)):

```
    POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.googleapis.com
    Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

    client_id=<your_client_id>&
    client_secret=<your_client_secret>&
    refresh_token=<refresh_token>&
    grant_type=refresh_token
```

P.S. I did not forget to replace client_id and other relevant data.

Comment: Show some code and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @ljmocic Did you have luck? As far as I see, Expo still does not provide API for refresh. So, I am in need to go with your workaround (code refreshing routine by myself)

Comment: Nope, haven't managed to get it working with Expo. But it was not the priority for me, so I didn't invest so much time in it. Maybe in the meantime some one found the solution.

Answer (score 1):

The same client ID that got the refresh token must be used to get another access token!

You are probably using this code on Android, for mobile devices Google doesn't give you a secret since it is not needed. You can remove the secret from the request and change the client ID to match your mobile client ID.